# difference between '^$' and '' in urls django

Tags: python, regex, django, django-urls

What is the difference between the below two url patterns in django?

```
url(r'^$', views.indexView, name='index'),

url(r'', include('registration.urls'))
```

To my understanding both  '^$' and '' refer to a empty string. What does '^$' and '' specify actually?

Comment: Just for the record: this is nothing Django-specific, it's just ordinary regexp syntax, cf https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Answer (score 50):

In regular expressions, `^` and `$` are special characters.

**`^` (Caret):**

`^` matches the start of the string.

Lets say my regex was `^a`, then the regex will look for `a` in the start of the string:

```
'a'    # Matches 'a' in 'a'  
'abc'  # Matches 'a' in 'abc'
'def'  # Not match because 'a' was not at the beginning
```

**`$` (Dollar sign):**

`$` matches the end of the string.

If my regex was `b$`, then it will match `b` at the end of the string:

```
'b'     # Matches 'b' in 'b'
'ab'    # Matches 'b' in 'ab'
'abc'   # Does not match
```

**Using `r'^$'`:**

Using both `^` and `$` together as `^$` will **match an empty line/string.**

```
url(r'^$', views.indexView, name='index')
```

When Django encounters an empty string, it will go to the `index` page.

**Using `r''`:**

When you use `r''`, **Django will look for an empty string anywhere in the URL, which is true for every URL.**

So, if your urlpattern was like this:

```
url(r'', views.indexView, name='index')
```

All your urls will go to `index` page.

Comment: Slight improvement regarding `r'^$'`: in case of an empty string in the url after the hostname, it will call the `indexview` view/function.

Comment: "With `r''`, all your urls will go to index page.": No, it depends on the urlpatterns before the `r''` pattern. If one matches, it will be taken and the pattern search will stop.

Comment: What is the difference between (using Django Rest): router.register(r'', viewsetname, 'views') and url(r'', viewsetname) ?

Comment: this is best explanation

Answer (score 11):

`^$`  means nothing is between the start and end ... this **only** matches the empty string

`''` means an empty string(but does not specify anything about the beginning or end of the entire string) so when you encounter anything in the string it say well that matches `'asdasd'` for example has a matching empty string at the beginning... the remaining is passed to the new url rules script (in this case everything remains)

if instead your second rule was `'a'` then it would match the first a in the `asdasd` and pass `sdasd` to the new url matching rule-set

*disclaimer that this is probably a gross oversimplification, but basically true*

Answer (score 1):

^$  - it specifies the start and end points of a URL string.

' ' - An empty string in URL method says, if any other URL pattern encountered that is not defined in the url pattern, then the corresponding empty string view should be called

Answer (score 1):

^$ means you are a matching the string between these two special characters